# How to change to another user in a remote machine using script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scripting

I need to perform some operation in a remote machine in which first I login as userA then change to userB

```
ssh userA@remoteHost   
userA$ 'sudo su userB'
```

Type password of userA to change to userB.
Do other operations as userB

I want to achieve this by running a script from my local machine to the remote machine.

```
localUser$ ssh userA@remoteHost 'bash -s' < script
```

Inside the script, some thing like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su userB

....
perform other operations as userB
```

At this moment when I run this script it asks for userA password to run the script first. Then asks for password for userA to switch to userB. But I am not able to input anything as the prompts do not persist. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not able to input anything as the prompts do not persist. How to achieve this ?

You already directed `script` to the stdin of the `ssh` command so the script is trying to read what is in `script` (but before flushes what is left there, which is a good practice for reading passwords interactively.

If you want to automate interactive actions, use `expect` script. If you want to use the script above, copy it first to the server and then run it there as

```
localUser$ ssh -t userA@remoteHost "./script"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sudo su userB`, 
you can use `sudo -S su - userB`